# how to create custom calender and add event on that calender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an attendance system where the functioning of the system depends on date. For instance, if it is local holiday or sunday, the control of system like Create Leave features is to be disabled. Also, the calender must show red on holidays. Is there any control in asp.net that helps me do this efficiently.how to create custom calender and add event on that calender and make system function according to calender!!!

Comment: You want ONLY asp.net? Or jQuery UI would be fine?

Comment: only asp.net control will be sufficient for now popeye..

Answer (score 1):

`Asp.Net` has a [calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/add3s294%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control. [Play with it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229445/Customizing-the-ASP-NET-Calendar-Control).

Comment: thanks man.. i was going through the control of asp.net calendar.. unfortunately, on click of next or previous tab located at top in month showing header, it is not working.. only selectionchanged event of calendar is used.. can you help ???